# Variable in nested function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, scope

The variable my_sound is declared in the first, outer function. So, I should be able to use it in the nested function. However the mouseout event produces no result. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var starting_pics = ["CN.gif", "EN.gif", "GN.gif"];
    var starting_sounds = ["CN.mp3", "EN.mp3", "GN.mp3"];

    var i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < starting_pics.length; i++) {
        $("<img/>").attr("src", "images/" + starting_pics[i]).appendTo("#main").addClass("pics");
    }

    $("#main").on("click", ".pics", function () {
        var i = $(this).index();
        var my_sound =($("<audio/>").attr("src", "audio/" + starting_sounds[i])).load().get(0).play();

        $("#main").on("mouseout", ".pics", function () {
            $("my_sound").animate({ volume: 0 }, 1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: my_sound is a variable not an element just do `my_sound.animate`

Comment: I don't think you mean to use `$("my_sound")`, you probably want `$(my_sound)` but even then it's already a jQuery object so just `my_sound.animate()` is enough.

Comment: my_sound.animate() still returns undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably that `.play()` doesn't return a jQuery object (or anything, for that matter, hence `undefined`).

Additionally, as the other comments have said, you don't want `$('my_sound').whatever` but rather just `my_sound.whatever` *if it were a jQuery object*, which it is not. So maybe you could try

```
var $my_sound = $("<audio />").attr("suchandsuch","etc");
$my_sound.load().get(0).play();
$my_sound.whatever();
```